# Method ActionFilterAttribute before controller ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to run method `ActionFilterAttribute` before controller `ActionFilterAttribute`

Example:

```
[Transaction(Order = 20)]
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
...
}

public class Test{} : BaseController {

[HttpPost]
        [WorkReportAccountsSettlementCreatedByCompanyDomainEvent]
        public virtual JsonResult Create(CreateStudentsWorkReportsListOverviewFormModel model)
        {
...
}

}
```

Problem is that `TransactionAttribute` is always executed before `WorkReportAccountsSettlementCreatedByCompanyDomainEventAttribute`

Why? I want oposite ...

Answer (score 1):

Why `TransactionAttribute` is executed before `WorkReportAccountsSettlementCreatedByCompanyDomainEventAttribute` is that the first one has the lower order.
You can take a look at [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx) where described all filters order.

If you will take a look on `FilterScope` enum you will see the following:

```
public enum FilterScope 
{
    First = 0,
    Global = 10,
    Controller = 20,
    Action = 30,
    Last = 100,
}
```

It means that even if you set `Order = 20` it still will be executed before because `Action = 30`.

Comment: Now I set [Transaction(Order = 80)] but is still executed before WorkReportAccountsSettlementCreatedByCompanyDomainEvent. Action is 30 so should be WorkReportAccountsSettlementCreatedByCompanyDomainEvent before but is not

Comment: Try to specify `[WorkReportAccountsSettlementCreatedByCompanyDomainEventAttribute(Order = 81)]`.

Comment: I tried but is the same. TransactionAttribute is still executed BEFORE WorkReportAccountsSettlementCreatedByCompanyDomainEventAttribute

I have no more ideas :(